# Help to find a triple integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus, integration

I need help to find the integration $\int\int\int_D (x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}dxdydz$

Where $D: 1\leq x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 4$; $ x,y,z\geq 0$.

Comment: Do you know spherical coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use spherical coordinates:

$$x=r \sin{\theta} \cos{\phi}$$
$$y=r \sin{\theta} \sin{\phi}$$
$$z=r \cos{\theta}$$

$$dx dy dz = r^2 \sin{\theta} dr d\theta d\phi$$

Note that, for the region you specify, $1 \le r \le 2$, $0 \le \theta \le \pi/2$, $0 \le \phi \le \pi/2$.  (First octant.)  Then the integral is

$$\int_1^2 dr \,r^2 \, r^{3} \, \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta \, \sin{\theta} \, \int_0^{\pi/2} d\phi $$

Can you take it from here?  I get $63 \pi/12$ as the result.

Comment: yes i can .. thank u very much

Comment: Shouldn't there be a sine in the expression for dxdydz? (I think you have it in the integral.)

Comment: @user84413: of course, thanks for pointing that out.